# Alert user if they hit back arrow

Tags: android, listener, alert, back-button

I am looking to alert the user if they hit the back button while in the application.. for instance, if the user is half way through using the application and they hit the back arrow, right now it just closes and they would lose all data if they accidentally hit it.

I would like to be able to alert the user with "Do you really want to exit?" so that if it was accidental, they can choose no and continue, and not lose any data.

I'm guessing I will need to implement some sort of listener??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override onbackpressed()  something like...

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Do you really want to exit?.").setCancelable(
                false).setPositiveButton("Quit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            YourActivity.this.finish();

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

Comment: While this literally addresses @Rob's question, I think it is the wrong solution for the wrong problem -- see my answer.

Comment: I agree that generally speaking your approach is the correct one, I still think there there are times that it is acceptable for user experience to override the default behavior.  The example in comments to your post of Gmail is a good example: I actually prefer getting a popup when composing an email asking if I would like to save or discard my response from the reply screen when hitting the back button rather than defaulting to saving it and restoring state (or worse: saving a draft that I just have to browse to then delete when I didn't want it saved).

Answer (score 1):

> if the user is half way through using the application and they hit the back arrow, right now it just closes and they would lose all data if they accidentally hit it.

Then don't lose the data. Save it in `onPause()`, if not to the permanent data store, to a temporary spot that you then check sometime later.

> I would like to be able to alert the user with "Do you really want to exit?" so that if it was accidental, they can choose no and continue, and not lose any data.

Please don't.

This addresses precisely one use case: the user pressing the BACK button. It completely ignores:

- the user pressing the HOME button
- the user getting a phone call
- the user responding to a `Notification`
- the user long-pressing on HOME (or pressing the recent-tasks button in Honeycomb) and switching to another task
- etc.

If losing the data is a problem for you when they press BACK, it is a problem for you in all those other cases as well. Hence, handle all the cases, not by interrupting the user when they are trying to leave, but by holding onto the data, then prompting them about the in-flight data if and when they choose to return.

Comment: I agree with this, but it is interesting to note that Google uses a similar paradigm in the gmail app when you press back while composing a new message.

Comment: @sgarman: Which is particularly odd, since Gmail already has the whole draft message concept. Ironically, it was Ms. Hackborn (a Googler) who took me to task over this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just override [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29). One caveat: it's since API 5.

Answer (score 0):

You should override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method of activity and provide logic there.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of other threads on this. Basically, override `onBackPressed()`